# Build a specific LINQ expression based on another LINQ expression and a value

Tags: linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

If I've got a LINQ expression of the form:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, string, bool>> filterExpression = (x, filterVal) => x.DisplayName.Contains(filterVal);
```

Is there any way I can get to the expression below?

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> filter = x => x.DisplayName.Contains("John");
```

I need to use the second expression in a Linq-to-Entities Where call.

Comment: Can this work? Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> filter = x => filterExpression.Compile()(x, "John");

Comment: Linq-to-Entities won't be able to serialise a compiled expression to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) that replaces the `ParameterExpression` with a `ConstantExpression`.

It would look something like

```
protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) {
    if (node.Name == "filterVal")
        return Expression.Constant(something);
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it's useful the way I solved it was:

```
public class MyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Visiting Parameter: " + node.Name);
        if (node.Name == "filterVal")
        {
            return Expression.Constant("John");
        }
        return node;
    }
}

Expression<Func<MyClass, string, bool>> filterExpression = (x, filterVal) => x.DisplayName.Contains(filterVal);
var filterExpBody = (new MyVisitor()).Visit(filterExpression.Body);
Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, bool>>(filterExpBody, filterExpression.Parameters[0]);
```