# wrap a linq expression with another linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I was thinking if without writing an ExpressionVisitor it's possible to solve this issue

```
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> multiply = (n1, n2) => n1 * n2;

Expression<Func<int, Expression<Func<int, int, int>>, Expression<Func<int, int>>>> power2 = 
              (adad, tabe) => Expression.Invoke(tabe, 
                                   Expression.Constant(adad), Expression.Constant(adad));

power2.Compile()(2, multiply);
```

the only point that I can't figure out is how to convert the invocation expression to the return type. if I set the return type to `dynamic` then it looks fine, but I wonder if there is better option to do that

Comment: If You set the type of `power2` to `Expression<Func<int, Expression<Func<int, int, int>>, InvocationExpression>>` it compiles, but then the last line produces the invocation expression, not the result of squaring a number. Is that What You want or did I miss something?

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012689/build-a-specific-linq-expression-based-on-another-linq-expression-and-a-value), i asked the same thing, but i prefer not to write an ExpressionVisitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Expression<Func<int, Expression<Func<int, int, int>>, Expression<Func<int>>>> power2 =
    (o, f) => Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(Expression.Invoke(
                  f, Expression.Constant(o), Expression.Constant(o)));
```

and then expression is:

```
var r = power2.Compile()(4, multiply);
//r = {() => Invoke((n1, n2) => (n1 * n2), 4, 4)}
```

if you want to invoke `r` then:

```
var r = power2.Compile()(4, multiply).Compile()();
//r is 16
```

---

**n.b.** I have changed the signature to return only `Func<int>` because the actual argument will be already embedded during the compilation.